# Implication of multiple MySQL keys with the same name

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, indexing, composite-key

Using separate queries I can add non-unique indexes to a MySQL table, each with its own key name, like this:

[image]

But when I use the database forge class of my PHP framework (CodeIgniter 3) to add several keys during a CREATE TABLE query, they all get the same **Key_name**, but with a different **Seq_in_index** value.

PHP Code:

```
$this->dbforge->add_key(['estimate_id', 'order_number']);
// produces: KEY `estimate_id_order_number` (`estimate_id `, `order_number `)
```

Resulting keys:

[image]

I don’t really know which is "better" so to speak. The latter table configuration seems to indicate that a single key is used to index both **estimate_id** and **order_id**.

Will that cause any problems, such as ambiguity between the fields?

Are there any performance implications for either table design?

What sort of situations might require distinct key names?

Comment: that add_key doesn't add several keys, it adds a single multi-column key.  it sounds like that's not what you want to do?  your multi-column key won't help look up by just order_number

Comment: `show create table yourtablename` is a much better way to see your table structure and indexes

Comment: @ysth ok so it's a multi-column key, I didn't realise that. I wonder why the framework create table method produces this by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [composite key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) also known as a composite index. Multiple columns are included in the BTREE index.

In your case the key is defined as

```
 ALTER TABLE tbl
     ADD KEY estimate_id_order_number (estimate_id, order_number)
```

The key's name `estimate_id_order_number` is just a name. You can use that name to [drop the key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-index.html) later if you decide you don't need it. You can use it to remind you the purpose of the index. It shows up in query plans. And if you must use an [index hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html), you use the index name. It serves no other purpose -- none -- during queries.

If you have a query like

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE estimate_id = 123 AND order_number = 321
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE estimate_id = 123 ORDER BY order_number
```

this index will make it run very fast: the query can be satisfied from the composite key.

But if you have

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE order_number = 321
```

it won't help: the composite index only helps when there's a WHERE clause mentioning its *first* column. But a key with the columns `(order_number, estimate_id)` will help.

Comment: index names are also used in index hints and shown in query plans